# Ionic buttons in header not responding to ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am sure this is a simple question but I have been absolutely pulling my hair out trying to get this to work. I have a button in my header that on click I want to fire a simple function that prints. I cannot get it to print on click!!

I'll paste the HTML and JS down below. I know for a fact that the controller is properly connected to the html view. It is an ABSTRACT state because I have the tabs as well. I am beginning to think you can't use a controller for abstract states? I just want my header to appear above the tabs

HTML:

```
 <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="clicked()">Seach</button>
     <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search-strong" ng-click="showFilterBar()">
    </button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="clicked()" >Test</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>

<!--

Create tabs with an icon and label, using the tabs-positive style.
Each tab's child <ion-nav-view> directive will have its own
navigation history that also transitions its views in and out.
-->

<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-light tabs-color-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


   <!-- Search Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Search" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/search">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/selfprofile">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-selfprofile"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

Javascript:

```
   .controller('tabCtrl', ['$state', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicFilterBar) {
console.log("tab control is on");
    $scope.places = [{name:'New York'}, {name: 'London'}, {name: 'Milan'}, {name:'Paris'}];


$scope.clicked = function() {
  console.log("test")
};


$scope.showFilterBar = function () {
  console.log("search button pressed");
    var filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
      cancelText: "<i class='ion-ios-close-outline'></i>",
      items: $scope.places,
      update: function (filteredItems, filterText) {
        $scope.places = filteredItems;
      }
    });
  };



}])
```

Just showing this is an abstract state:

```
  .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabsL1.html',
        controller: 'tabCtrl'
        })
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I tried manually doing that in a single page and it seemed to work. I am pretty confused why it will not work in this case and if there is a work around.

Comment: Just checking, you do want this to just print in the console right? I can see it when I click it.